# Find and remove empty properties from objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my array of objects:

```js
var data = [
  {
    "label": "HOME",
    "href": "web-tutor99.com",
    "children": [{}]
  }, 
  {
    "href": "web-tutor99.com",
    "label": "HTML5"
  }
];
```

It is a multidimensional object and here the children property is empty. How can I find empty properties like this and remove them using jQuery?

Comment: what is the purpose, what are you trying to achieve by removing the item?? Like I can't see any practical reason why you would waste cycles to calculate and remove this item.  If its because its a display thing.  Then simply check if its empty first, then display if not.

Comment: Is `[{}]` an empty value for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
data = [{
      "label": "HOME",
      "href": "web-tutor99.com",
      "children": [{}]
    }, {
      "href": "web-tutor99.com",
      "label": "HTML5"
    }];

    alert("Before : "+JSON.stringify(data));
     //console.log(data);

    checkEmptyObj(data);

     alert("After : "+JSON.stringify(data));

    function checkEmptyObj(data) {
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        if ($.isPlainObject(value) || $.isArray(value)) {
          checkEmptyObj(value);
        }
        //alert(key+":"+$.isEmptyObject(value));
        if (value === "" || value === null || $.isEmptyObject(value)) {
          delete data[key];
        }
      });

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this..

```
for (var i in data) {
  if (test[i].children === null || test[i].children === undefined || test[i].children.length<=0) {
    delete test[i].children;
  }
}
```

But I see no practical use in wasting CPU cycles looping through objects to remove empty objects.

Not really sure what you're trying to achieve.  But you're better off just checking if its empty, and then not displaying if its the case.

Comment: This would not work on his example project since the `children` property is neither `null`, nor `undefined`, nor `length` of 0

Comment: Oh yeah youre right.  Didnt see those extra brackets.  My bad.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a (if nested, recursive) function looping through all elements and check if the it has a value, if not, [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) that property.

In your example object you have the problem that the `children` property is by far not empty - it is a property with a value of an array containing one empty object. Depending on your scenario you'd have to run through your object multiple times, removing empty entries step by step (could probably do some optimization).

As a final note, you can use [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to loop through an object's properties and [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to loop through an object's/array's values.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following pure JS snippet takes care of the job. You can check it @ [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/luboluwiri/1/edit?js,console)

```
var data = [{"label":"HOME","href":"web-tutor99.com","children":[{}]},{"href":"web-tutor99.com","label":"HTML5"}];

function walkJSONObj(obj){
  for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj[prop].constructor === Array) {        //if prop is an array 
      walkJSONArray(obj[prop]);                   //go walk through the arrays
      obj[prop].length === 0 && delete obj[prop]; //if on return the array is empty delete it
    }
    else typeof obj[prop] === 'undefined' && delete obj[prop]; //delete undefined props
  }    
}

function walkJSONArray(arr){
  for (var l = arr.length-1; l >= 0; l--) {
    walkJSONObj(arr[l]); // go walk the item objects
    if (Object.keys(arr[l]).length === 0 && JSON.stringify(arr[l]) === JSON.stringify({})) {
      arr.splice(l, 1);  // if on return the object is empty delete it
    }
  }
}

walkJSONArray(data);
```