# condensing the array object recursively in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects in the below format:

```
{
  "country": "India",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Karnataka",
      "type": "State",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "city"
        },
        {
          "name": "Bangalore",
          "type": "city"
        },
        {
          "name": "Mangalore",
          "type": "city"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Kerala",
      "type": "State",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "city"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Maharashtra",
      "type": "State",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Mumbai",
          "type": "city"
        },
        {
          "name": "Pune",
          "type": "city"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Every object has a children element which contains the details of the element. I need to recursively iterate through the <strike>json</strike> object and remove all the nodes whose `name` is empty string up till the root. For the above json format, the output should be like below:

```
{
  "country": "India",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Karnataka",
      "type": "State",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Bangalore",
          "type": "city"
        },
        {
          "name": "Mangalore",
          "type": "city"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Kerala",
      "type": "State",
      "children": [
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Maharastra",
      "type": "State",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Mumbai",
          "type": "city"
        },
        {
          "name": "Pune",
          "type": "city"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How to do this in javascript recursively using Underscorejs.

Comment: @RayonDabre—seems to me *reduceRight* and delete unwanted members is better, but does underscore.js have that? If not there's the built–in one.

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171667/find-and-remove-empty-properties-from-objects/36171824) might help you

Comment: I don't know how important it is for you to preserve the original data object but if you go array functions way you will probably lose it unless you clone the object in the first place by some means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a recursive solution with [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
function filterName(a) {
    if (a.name) {
        if (Array.isArray(a.children)) {
            a.children = a.children.filter(filterName);
        }
        return true;
    }
}

var object = { "country": "India", "children": [{ "name": "Karnataka", "type": "State", "children": [{ "name": "", "type": "city" }, { "name": "Bangalore", "type": "city" }, { "name": "Mangalore", "type": "city" }] }, { "name": "Kerala", "type": "State", "children": [{ "name": "", "type": "city" }] }, { "name": "Maharashtra", "type": "State", "children": [{ "name": "Mumbai", "type": "city" }, { "name": "Pune", "type": "city" }] }] };

object.children.forEach(filterName);
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + "</pre>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function condense(arr) {

  arr.children = arr.children.map(function(c) {
    c.children = c.children.filter(function(c1) {
      return c1.name;
    });
    return c;
  });

  return arr;
}
```

I iterate through the children (with `map`), then filter the children array with `filter`. Only the children with a name not null or empty will be kept.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Shitsu/ddq3qv2x/).

Comment: I tried similar approach. I wanted to attempt  this with recursion.

Comment: Why ? You only have two depth levels. Furthermore, at the first level, you keep empty children, on the second one you delete them. It does not seem like a good recursion candidate.

Answer (score 1):

Not *au fait* with underscore.js. You can do this with ES5 *reduceRight* and delete members that you don't want, it should be more efficient than other approaches. The following uses recursion (which isn't as efficient as serial processing but is likely less code), so you can nest the objects as deep as you like:

```js
function removeEmpty(obj) {
  obj.children.reduceRight(function (acc, child, i) {
    if (!child.name) {
      obj.children.splice(i, 1);
    } else if (child.children) {
      removeEmpty(child);
    }
    return null;
  }, null);
  return obj;
}

// Test
var data = {
  "country": "India",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Karnataka",
      "type": "State",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "city"
        },
        {
          "name": "Bangalore",
          "type": "city"
        },
        {
          "name": "Mangalore",
          "type": "city"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Kerala",
      "type": "State",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "city"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Maharashtra",
      "type": "State",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Mumbai",
          "type": "city"
        },
        {
          "name": "Pune",
          "type": "city"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


document.write('Original:<br>' + JSON.stringify(data) + '<br><br>' +
               'Modified:<br>' + JSON.stringify(removeEmpty(data)));
```

Comment: Oh, the usage of `reduceRight` is so confusing here, as you're not reducing anything…

Comment: Yes, it's just to iterate from length to 0, the accumulator is ignored. Perhaps there should be a *forEachRight*? ;-) Thinking about it now, the *return null* can be omitted.

Comment: Maybe also `_` instead of `acc`

Answer (score 1):

This is very specific to your example.

[Link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpt9erdt/)

```js
var obj = {
  "country": "India",
  "children": [{
    "name": "Karnataka",
    "type": "State",
    "children": [{
      "name": "",
      "type": "city"
    }, {
      "name": "Bangalore",
      "type": "city"
    }, {
      "name": "Mangalore",
      "type": "city"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Kerala",
    "type": "State",
    "children": [{
      "name": "",
      "type": "city"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Maharashtra",
    "type": "State",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Mumbai",
      "type": "city"
    }, {
      "name": "Pune",
      "type": "city"
    }]
  }]
};

//Before
document.write("BEFORE: "+JSON.stringify(obj));
//After
document.write("AFTER: "+JSON.stringify(checkJSON(obj)));

function checkJSON(obj) {
  $.each(obj.children, function(index, value) {
    if ($.isArray(value.children)) {
      $.each(value.children, function(index, value) {
        if (value.name == '') {
          delete value.name;
        }
      });
    }
  });
  return obj;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the shortest way, but it works:

```
obj.children = _.each(obj.children, filter);

function filter(child, index, arr) {
  if (child && child.name === '') {
    // remove the ones without name
    arr.splice(index, 1);

  } else if (_.has(child, 'children')) {
    // remove nested children
    child.children = _.each(child.children, filter);

    // check for empty children array and remove it (if needed)
    /*
    if (child.children.length === 0) {
      delete child['children'];
    }
    */
  }

  return child;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gnmosu5p/2/

Answer (score 1):

I know a recursive approach is asked but i can't help myself from giving a single liner here.

```
var newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data).replace(/{"name":"".+?},?/g, ""));
```

where `data` is the initially given object to be restructured.

It's somewhat slower than array functions but one advantage of this method is preserving the original data object as it is while all array methods will override the original data object unless you clone it.